# Need help proving $[0,1]$ is Borel isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: probability, analysis

I am reading this note on probability theory

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/

and in the proof of Lemma 12, professor Tao wrote that

**"Let us call two topological spaces Borel isomorphic if their corresponding Borel structures are isomorphic as measurable spaces. Using the binary expansion, we see that $[0,1]$ is Borel isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ (the countable number of points that have two binary expansions can be easily permuted to obtain a genuine isomorphism)"**,

which I am having difficulty to justify. In other words, I need to find a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ such that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are measurable. In addition, I am not sure what topology to put on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The topology on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is the product topology coming from the discrete topology on each of the factors; more intuitively, the space is "all infinite binary sequences" and the basic open sets are the sets of the form "all sequences beginning with $\sigma$" for $\sigma$ a finite binary string (for example, "the set of all infinite binary sequences which begin with either $001$ or $1111111$" is open; it's the union of the two basic open sets, "the set of all infinite binary sequences which begin with $001$" and "the set of all infinite binary sequences which begin with $1111111$.")

Comment: Expansion of points in $[0,1]$ to base $2$ gives this isomorphism. For points with two expansions choose the infinite expansion.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Of course, that's not *exactly* the whole thing, since the result isn't quite a bijection.

Comment: It is a bijection if you use non-terminating expansions.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your answers. I believe that I have justified this, although, I have not written it down rigorously yet.

Here is the idea: let $f:[0,1] \to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ be the binary expansion of numbers in $[0,1]$. We choose $f(x)$ such that if $x$ has two different binary expansions, then choose $f(x)$ to be the one with infinitely repeating $0$ at the end.

But $f$ is only injective. So we need to modify $f$ a little bit. Notice that the set of points $x$ that have two binary expansions is countable. In other words, the set of points in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ that are not in $f([0,1])$ is countable.

Put it differently, let $A$ be the subset of $[0,1]$ whose elements have two binary expansions. Then $A$ is countable, so we can write $A=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Originaly, we map each $a_n$ to $f(a_n)$, where $f(a_n)$ was chosen to be the expansion with infinitely repeating $0$ at the end. Call $f'(a_n)$ be the non-terminating expansion of $a_n$. Now, we modify $f$ such that $f$ maps $a_k$ to the set $\{f(a_n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $k$ odd, and $f$ maps $a_k$ to the set   $\{f'(a_n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $k$ even. Keep $f$ unchanged for other points. Then, $f$ is bijective.

Now, we need to show that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is Borel measurable. This is easy:

To see why $f$ is measurable, take for example and open set in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, to be something like  $E=\{1\}\times\{1\}\times\{0\}\times\{1\}\times\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. Then $f^{-1}(E)$ will be a closed set such that maybe a countable points of $f^{-1}(E)$ are shifted. But that is not a problem because $f^{-1}(E)$ is still a Borel set.

For measurability of $f^{-1}$. Let $(a,b)$ be an open subset of $[0,1]$. Let $[a_n,b_n]$ be  such that $a_n, b_n$ have terminating binary expansion, and $[a_n,b_n]$ increases to $(a,b)$. It is easy to see that $f([a_n,b_n])$ is closed (mod a countable set, of course) and hence Borel. Thus, $f((a,b))$ is Borel.