# Borel isomorphism between $[0, 1]$ and the space of all binary sequences

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

From part of the proof of Lemma 12 in Tao's note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-681889

We have the following statement:

Let us call two topological spaces Borel isomorphic if their corresponding Borel structures are isomorphic as measurable spaces. Using the binary expansion, we see that $[0,1]$ is Borel isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$(the countable number of points that have two binary expansions can be easily permuted to obtain a genuine isomorphism).

**Question**: How do we show that this map is indeed measurable? (I guess the question partly arise from the confusion about the Borel structure of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. An earlier similar post exists: [Need help proving $[0,1]$ is Borel isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896867/need-help-proving-0-1-is-borel-isomorphic-to-0-1-mathbbn) Yet I don’t fully understand the answer provided there.

Comment: Regarding your final sentence, please link the post and please ask a more specific question. That you "want to hear more on the topic" is too vague.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should show that the Borel isomorphism is a Bi-measurable function when you considering appropriate topological bases on both spaces. Remember that if $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ generate $\mathcal{B}$, then $f:(X,\mathcal{B}')\to (Y, \mathcal{B})$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(C)\in \mathcal{B'}$ for all $C\in \mathcal{C}$.

Since intervals of the form $(\frac{j_1}{2^n},\frac{j_2}{2^n}]$ generate the Borel sigma algebra of $[0,1]$, show that they are mapped to cylinder sets with restrictions on the $n$ first coordinates. The latter form a basis for the topology on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and generate the Borel sigma-algebra on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can we understand the Borel structure on $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbf N}$ to be the product of $\mathbf N$ copies of the discrete algebra on $\{0, 1\}$?

Comment: @KKslider I think the answer is yes, though I do not think it useful for the sake of understanding the discussed isomorphism.